# Capturing changes in field in python

Tags: python, spyder, duration, calculation

I have a vehicle monitoring log file which consist of the following fields:

Index, Timestamp(date time), lat, long, mode(denote as 0,2,4), vehicle model(denote as x,y and z)

.

The whole idea of the program is split into 2 part

1. Is to capture the time when the mode field switch to each and every mode.
2. By using the capture timing to calculate the total duration each vehicle stays in their mode.
   .

   ```
   1,2016-05-02 09:14:32.242, lat, long, 2, x
   2,2016-05-02 09:14:37.341, lat, long, 2, x
   3,2016-05-02 09:14:39.142, lat, long, 2, x
   4,2016-05-02 09:14:42.736, lat, long, 2, x
   5,2016-05-02,09:14:48.212, lat, long, 0, x   //Capturing this timing for X
   6,2016-05-02,09:14:52.222, lat, long, 0, x
   7,2016-05-02,09:14:56.335, lat, long, 2, x   //Capturing this timing for X
   8,2016-05-02,09:14:58.242, lat, long, 2, x
   9,2016-05-02,09:15:01.742, lat, long, 2, y
   10,2016-05-02,09:15:03.862, lat, long, 2, x
   11,2016-05-02,09:15:13.277, lat, long, 2, y
   12,2016-05-02,09:15:24.436, lat, long, 2, y
   13,2016-05-02,09:15:32.211, lat, long, 0, y  //capturing this timing for Y
   ```

The end state of the program is to be able to calculate the total duration of each vehicle in each mode.
Please advice on any methods to tackle such issue.
Sorry if this is a duplicate question as i do not know what exact topic or heading such question belongs.

.

Im currently using Spyder IDE and need someone to point me a direction to research on!

Thank you!

P.S. As the data are confidential, these are just some test data without the actual lat long input

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import csv
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import messagebox
 from tkinter import ttk
 from itertools import groupby
 import datetime

 def get_data(event):

 x = str1Var.get()
 y = str2Var.get()
 mydataset = pd.read_csv(x + '.txt')

 print (mydataset.shape)

 mydataset.sort_values([1,0])
 print(mydataset)
 mydataset.to_csv(y +'.txt')
```

As of now, I've only done reading file and sorting it with respect to the time. Still looking for logic and method to explore further.

Comment: So, could you please share the *code* you have?

Comment: Hi @vahdet . Post updated! :)